Do lattices with small covering radius have sublattices with small covering radius?
For me a lattice is a discrete subgroup of $\mathbb R^n$. The linear span of a lattice, written $\Lambda \otimes \mathbb R$, is the $\mathbb R$-vector subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ generated by $\Lambda$. The covering radius of a lattice $\Lambda$ is the minimum value of $r$ such that for all $x \in \Lambda\otimes \mathbb R$ of $\Lambda$ there exists $y\in \Lambda$ with $\|x-y\|\leq r$.
What is the least constant $c_n$ such that every lattice of rank $n$ with covering radius $r$ contains a sublattice of rank $n-1$ with covering radius $\leq c_n r$?
I can prove that $c_n \leq \sqrt{n-1}$ by checking that the covering radius of a lattice of rank $n$ is at least half its $n$th successive minimum and at most $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}$ times its $n$th successive minimum, and then passing to the sublattice generated by the shortest $n-1$ linearly independent vectors in $\Lambda$, whose $(n-1)$th successive minimum is the $(n-1)$th successive minimum of $\Lambda$ and hence is at most the $n$th successive minimum of $\Lambda$.
Both the lower and upper bound proofs for a lattice $\Lambda$ themselves involve the sublattice $\Lambda'$ generated by the shortest $n-1$ linearly independent vectors in $\Lambda$. The lower bound for the covering radius $r$ is considering a vector of distance $r+\epsilon$ from $0$ in a direction perpendicular to $\Lambda' \otimes \mathbb R$. The closest vector to this point has a distance at most $2r+\epsilon$ from $0$ and does not lie in $\Lambda'$, bounding the last successive minimum. For the upper bound on the covering radius, which more precisely is $\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^2}$, one proceeds by induction on $n$, finding $y \in \Lambda$ such that the hyperpalne $y + \Lambda'\otimes \mathbb R$ has distance at most $\lambda_n/2$ to $x$, orthogonally projects $y + \Lambda'\otimes \mathbb R$ to that hyperplane, and then using the inductive hypothesis. Presumably both of these bounds are (well?-)known.
It is not even obvious to me whether $c_n \leq 1$ for $n>2$. If $c_n \leq 1$ for all $n$ then the series of invariants "the minimum covering radius of a rank $r$ sublattice of $\Lambda$" which interpolate between the covering radius and packing radius are totally ordered. This was my original motivation for this question, although one could ask what the motivation is for wondering whether this interpolation of covering radius and packing radius is totally ordered and I wouldn't have an answer.

Could you please explain for uneducated people like me, what is $\Lambda\otimes \mathbb{R}$ and how do you take $||x-y||$ when $x\in \Lambda\otimes \mathbb{R}$ and $y\in \Lambda$?

But this set is dense in the linear span of $\Lambda$, no? So it is the same as to consider the linear span of $\Lambda$, right?

@AlekseiKulikov This set is the linear span of $\Lambda$. I was just trying to express this more compactly...

(That is, it is the subgroup $\mathbf R\Lambda$ generated by products $xy$ for $x \in \Lambda$ and $y \in \mathbf R$.)

@R.vanDobbendeBruyn Oh, sorry, yes, I don't remember why I thought the additive generation wasn't necessary.

Note: $c_1=0$, and $c_2=\sqrt{3}$ achieved by the regular triangular lattice.

By this, up to a multiplicative factor 2 you can replace the covering radius with the expected (squared) Euclidean norm with respect to the uniform distribution on the voronoi cell. I think you can then reduce to comparing this integral with ann integral over codimension 1 sections of the voronoi cell? Seems like the kind of thing that is often studied in convex analysis, so might be more tractable.

@MarkSchultz-Wu The issue is that the Voronoi cell of a sublattice may be larger than a codimension 1 section of the Voronoi cell of the lattice, since the closest point in $\Lambda$ to a given point in $\mathbb R \Lambda'$ need not lie in $\Lambda'$.

@YCor $c_2 =\sqrt{3}/2$, no?

@WillSawin Ah, yes. (I computed correctly the covering radius of the 2-dim regular triangular lattice, but miscomputed that of the lattice $\mathbf{Z}\subset\mathbf{R}$ which is $1/2$ and not $1$.)

$\DeclareMathOperator{\vol}{vol} \newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$
I can prove that $c_n>\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi e}}>0.48$ for large enough $n$ [I previously thought I had a lower bound of $2$ so this is only  a partial answer to your question of comparing $c_n$ and $1$].
Let $v_n = \frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2+1)}$ denote the volume of the unit ball in $n$-space, and recall that $v_n^{1/n} \sim \sqrt{\frac{2\pi e}{n}}$.
For a lattice $\Lambda$, write $\mu(\Lambda)$ its covering radius, and note that $\mu(L) \ge \frac{\vol(\Lambda)^{1/n}}{v_n^{1/n}}$.
Define $\mu'(\Lambda) = \inf \mu(\Lambda')$ where $\Lambda'$ ranges over rank $n-1$ sublattices of $\Lambda$. If I read your definition correctly, your $c_n$ is $\sup_{\Lambda}\frac{\mu'(\Lambda)}{\mu(\Lambda)}$, where $\Lambda$ ranges over lattices of rank $n$.
Now let $\Lambda = \Z^n$. We have $\mu(\Lambda) = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}$. On the other hand, for every rank $n-1$ sublattice $\Lambda'\subset \Z^n$ we have $\vol(\Lambda')\ge 1$, so that $\mu(\Lambda') \ge v_{n-1}^{-\frac{1}{n-1}}$, and therefore $\mu'(\Lambda) \ge v_{n-1}^{-\frac{1}{n-1}}$.
This gives $c_n \ge v_{n-1}^{-\frac{1}{n-1}}\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}$, which converges to $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi e}}>0.48$ as $n\to \infty$.

One can actually get $c_n \geq \sqrt{ \frac{n-1}{n}} $ using $\Lambda = \mathbb Z^n$. Any codimension $1$ sublattice has the form ${x_1,\dots,x_n\in \mathbb Z\mid \sum_{i=1}^n a_ix_i=0}$ for integers $a_1,\dots,a_n$. The linear span is ${x_1,\dots,x_n\in \mathbb R\mid \sum_{i=1}^n a_ix_i=0}$. If $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ is even then there exists a point in the span with all $x_i$ half-integers, and otherwise $a_j$ is odd for some $j$ and there exists a point in the span with $a_j$ an integer and all other $a_i$ half-integers. The distance of such a point is at least $\sqrt{\frac{n-1}{2}}$.

@WillSawin Indeed! I initially thought about my argument using random lattices (which are semistable, so the argument applies) and for arbitrary codimensions, but then specialised to Z^n and did not think about looking more precisely at the shapes of the sublattices.

@WillSawin Using Theorem 1.5 here I think we can prove $c_n \le \sqrt{2\pi e}\cdot 10(\log n + 10)^{3/2}$. I will write the proof when I have a bit of time, unless I find a mistake.
